# Swift crash report `function signature specialization`

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I'm getting the cryptic crash report, and for the life of me I cannot figure out what is going on that could cause this error.  However, I'm not a skilled iOS/Swift developer, so perhaps it's obvious to someone else!

Here's the stack:

```
function signature specialization <Arg[1] = Value Promoted from Box> of closure #1 () -> () in Company.LoginViewController.(logIn in _10D245F74F8D2701C8F7339313EB1733)() -> ()
LoginViewController.swift - line 275
SIGABRT

libsystem_kernel.dylib
__pthread_kill
libsystem_c.dylib
abort
libswiftCore.dylib
0x103964000 + 2666636
libswiftCore.dylib
0x103964000 + 2666896
libswiftCore.dylib
0x103964000 + 2869624
Company
function signature specialization <Arg[1] = Value Promoted from Box> of closure #1 () -> () in Company.LoginViewController.(logIn in _10D245F74F8D2701C8F7339313EB1733)() -> () LoginViewController.swift:275
Company
_T0Ieg_IeyB_TR LoginViewController.swift:0
Company
_T0So8NSStringCIeyBy_SSIegx_TRTA AuthenticationManager.swift:0
Company
function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed> of closure #1 (__ObjC.AFOAuthCredential) -> () in Company.AuthenticationManager.authenticate(with: Swift.String, password: Swift.String, success: (Swift.String) -> (), failure: (__ObjC.INTAuthenticationError) -> ()) -> () AuthenticationManager.swift:105
```

Here is the relevant function:

```
private func logIn() {
    beginAuthentication()

    let credentials = INTUserCredentials()
    credentials.username = email.text
    credentials.password = password.text

    authenticationModel.logIn(with: credentials, success: { [unowned self] in
// *** Crashes here, oddly on an empty line ***
        let finish = { [weak self] in
            self?.endAuthentication()
            if let delegate = self?.delegate {
                delegate.authenticationViewControllerDidLogin(self?.registrationInfoContainer)
            }
        }
    }, failure: { [weak self] errorMessage in
        self?.showErrorMessage(errorMessage)
    })
}
```

Comment: A which line exactly does it crash?

Comment: I updated it to include the relevant line that it crashes, and removed some unrelated code to make things clearer.  Sorry for not providing that detail.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the object that you reference as self (LoginViewController?) is getting disposed? I could imagine, that the signature of the function logIn of your authenticationModel-class requires non optional attribute. However, after calling logIn() function the object is no more used and is disposed (because of [unowned self])... just put a break point in your dealloc function and see what happens. By the way, the dealloc function should not be empty to make the break point to stop

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  When you say "just put a break point in your dealloc function and see what happens" what do you mean I should look for specifically?

Comment: Also, would it possibly solve the issue, according to your theory, to change from `[unowned self]` to `[weak self]`?

Comment: My theory is, that you can remove [unowned self] at all. That should not make a retain cycle... What is the name of the class that contains your private func logIn() ? If you put a break point into dealloc function of this class, you can check whether it will be disposed. I had yesterday the same issue as you and could solve it by removing [unowned self]. I my case I had no retain cycles